# php генерация/выгрузка zip на лету без темпового файла

Tags: php, zip

Для проекта на PHP потребовалась выгрузка данных в zip. Данные динамические и представляют собой довольно увесистые файлы. В общей сложности архив может занимать до 800мб.

На данный момент генерация реализована через класс ZipAchive.

```
...какой-то код до

$archive = 'filestorage/temp/'.$fileName;

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files = FilesBank::getFilesInfo($photoIds);
foreach($files as &$file) {
    $zip->addFile($file['phusicalPath'], $file['name']);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($archive));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
readfile($archive);
unlink($archive);
```

Я использую промежуточный темповый файл, как результат, чудовищная задержка перед скачиванием в 20-40 секунд.

Как можно реализовать мгновенную выдачу файла без предварительного создания темпового файла?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244786/1216425 ? или библиотеки из соседних  ответов

Comment: Вариант интересный, но хотелось бы обойтись штатными средствами.

Comment: Это ж сколько тогда данные займут php-памяти...

Comment: Не нужно держать всё в памяти, нужно использовать что-то вроде потоков(как в Java OutputStream). Т.е. читать по мере выгрузки данных пользователю. Неужели в php нет ничего подобного.

Comment: Указанная либа в первом комментарии для php7, я юзаю php 5.6.